# Compiling AOSP , emulator failed to create drawable, Could not make gles 2.x context current! Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, android-emulator, ubuntu-16.04, android-source

After compiling AOSP with lunch aosp_arm-eng command emulator fails to run below is the output of $ emulator

Couldn't statvfs() path: No such file or directory

emulator: WARNING: encryption is off

failed to create drawable

failed to create drawable

failed to create drawable

failed to create drawable

failed to create drawable

failed to create drawable

failed to create drawable

failed to create drawable

getGLES2ExtensionString: Could not make GLES 2.x context current!

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to change emulated graphics to `Software`.
   [image: Emulator configuration]
2. Try to start emulator with parameter `-gpu off` manually:

   `~/.android/avd/emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -gpu off -no-snapstorage -avd Nexus_5X_API_28`

   Nexus_5X_API_28 is the name of your emulator.

Comment: i am not using android studio i am compiling AOSP with linux terminal i could not get it to launch, after 8-9 hours of build compilation i am not able to get it run on an emulator when ever i try to run command $emulator in terminal it gives me the error i explained in question